# Try/Catch and Loop Control

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm confused about this try/catch statement

```
public int MakeMove() {
    int x = 0; //counter for moves

    try {
        // tests to see if potential move has been reached
        if (board[currentRow + (vertical[x])][currentColumn + (horizontal[x])] != 0) {
            // increments x until a good move is reached.
            while ((board[currentRow + (vertical[x])][currentColumn + (horizontal[x])] != 0)) {
                x++;
                if (x == 8) { //breaks if all moves are tried
                    return 1;
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    //should catch any tries to move piece off board, catches the exception and increments x
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        x++;
        if(x == 8) {//breaks if all moves are tried
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

How this should work: horizontal[] and vertical[] are two int[]s which each hold the value for a chess knight's possible moves, i.e. 2 horizontal and 1 vertical out would be one move. Then it should assign a non zero movenumber to the "square".
The try/catch bit should catch any moves out of the board, increment x, and then go through the loop again. But whenever it goes through the statement it doesn't go through the first if again; instead it goes to the second if and generates an exception. I'm not sure what statement would return control in that way.

Comment: Just for future design, you shouldn't use exceptions as part of your normal program logic.

Comment: +1 Chris. @Alex, you want to structure your code in such a way that exceptions never happen. They're EXCEPTions, not EXPECTations. :-)

Comment: Never ever use try-catch Exception handling as flow control structure. It is for exception handling only. IMHO this is poor Java code.

Comment: Agreed w/ @Chris, exceptions for control flow are bad.  Also, this is a great question that wants a http://sscce.org/ -- I tried to paste the code above in to start some suggested changes, but had to tie off too many things and lost interest.

Comment: Thanks everyone Ill do that, new to Java so all this help is appreciated. Thanks for trying anyways andersoj ;)

Answer (score 4):

You wrote:

> The try/catch bit should catch any
>   moves out of the board, increment x,
>   and then go through the loop again.

No, it shouldn't.  You seem to be thinking of an exception handler (the "catch bit") as if it is a method that is called when an exception happens, that will return control back to where it was called from.  That's not how they work.

When an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs in your code, control jumps to the exception handler.  All processing of the code within the `try` block is terminated -- it's not going to be resumed.  The code within the `catch` block is executed.  If `x==8` your method will return a value; but otherwise, your exception handler just increments x and ends.  That means that execution of your code picks up after the end of the `catch` block.  You haven't shown the rest of your method -- I think there must be more since it is required to return a value -- so I can't say for sure what's happening next, but this could lead to any number of problems.

Exception handling is simply inappropriate here.  Test your coordinates against the size of the board explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Move the try catch inside the loop if you want it to reenter the loop after the catch body finishes.

But really, listen to everybody who says you shouldn't use exceptions for this.

Comment: Moving it inside the loop wouldn't be helpful anyway, because the exception he's trying to catch is generated by the loop condition, not by the body of the loop.

Comment: @Dave Costa, good point.  Some restructuring of the loop is required.